# Functions less that $N-N^\theta$ for all $\theta<1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-inequalities

I am working with a supervisor on a topic about normal numbers, and a certain class of functions came up. It is the class for which $0 \le f(N) \le N-N^\theta$ for all $0<\theta<1$. He said that there are many such functions, but I can't understand how there can be other than the zero function. I was wondering if anyone can help explain how there can be a function that fits this and what it might be? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For any $\theta < 1$, $\log N < N - N^{\theta}$ eventually.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem if $f$ is allowed to be negative. Is there a restriction on $f$ to nonnegative numbers?

Comment: Can $\theta<0$?  Must $f(N)\le N-N^\theta$ for all $N$ real or only $N>0$?

Comment: $\theta$, and $f$ both have to be non negative, sorry for lack of clarity. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: The thing you seem to be missing (and the others mention) is that we ask only $f(n) < n - n^\theta$ eventually; there is some $C$ that depends on $f$ and $\theta,$ such that  $f(n) < n - n^\theta$ when $n > C.$ Perhaps the easiest example is $f(n) = \beta n$ for some fixed $0 < \beta < 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when
$\theta$ is close to $1$,
so let
$\theta = 1-c$
where $c$ is small.

$N-N^{\theta}
=N-N^{1-c}
=N(1-N^{-c})
=N(1-\dfrac1{N^c})
\gt N(1-\dfrac1{\ln N})
$
since
$\ln N < N^c$
for any $c > 0$ for all
large enough $N$.

Therefore one possibility is
$N-N/\ln N$.

Comment: Thank you, this helped clear it up a lot. I was wondering if you were able to offer any guidance on finding the largest function that fit this bound was? If there is one? Thank you

Comment: Nope - no largest function. Use $N-N/f(N)$ when $f(N)$ grows slower and slower gets a larger and larger function. A standard slow grower is the k-fold iterated log.